# How to fix java rest API? Keep getting 404's

Tags: java, rest, api, maven, web-applications

I followed this tutorial (https://programmerscuriosity.com/2016/09/27/simple-jersey-example-with-intellij-idea-ultimate-and-tomcat/) to create a simple Rest API in java with tomcat, but I keep getting a 404 error, and I can't see where I went wrong.

I'm guessing the error is some where in my configuration.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.demo</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleJersey</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

MyResource.java

```
package demo;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Created by marom on 27/09/16.
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

My project structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VbLD.jpg

Added ressources to the WEB-INF
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnTI2.jpg

Tomcat configuration
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFhIO.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqrFY.jpg

404 from localhost:8080/rest/myresource
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIzz8.jpg

Comment: what is the context root of your application?

Comment: By context root are you referring to the localhost context? If you look at the tomcat config images, it should be `http://localhost:8080/` and application context `/`

Comment: use @Path("/myresource") instead of @Path("myresource")

Comment: `@Path("/myresource")` doesn't help @Nitika

Comment: change <param-value>com.demo</param-value> to <param-value>demo</param-value> as your MyResource.java resides in demo

Comment: Yay! That fixed it. Thank you very much. Could you submit an answer and then i'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your MyResource.java resides in demo package. You need to change the package mapping in web.xml 
**(param-value of jersey.config.server.provider.packages)**

updated web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>demo</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```